# Modifying platform specific configuration when using phonegap build

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am trying to use PhoneGap's File API to access an android device's file system. I am using PhoneGap Build to build the projects though and I can't figure out where to insert those details (such as the uses-perissions in the AndroidManifest).

I'm not very sure if this is possible at all, if it is could you let me know how to do the same for iOS and windows phone as well.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access the file system you need to add the following anywhere inside your config.xml:

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
```

You will also need to include the following tag in the `<head>` of the page that is trying to access that functionality (ie. index.html or myPage.html):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
```

Once that is done, it should work.